# MongoDB Kafka Source Connector - copy.exisintg.pipeline config

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm running a MongoDB Kafka source connector (official mongodb connector version 1.7.0), and defining both `pipeline` and `copy.existing.pipeline` properties in order to filter some columns- see below full source connector config.

The problem I'm having is that the `copy.existing.pipeline` seems to work and filter the columns during the `copy.existing` phase, but when the connector finishing and moves to the stream phase it seems like the `pipeline` property is ignored and I'm getting the documents without any filtering.

```
{
  "name": "connector1",
  "config": {
    "name": "connector1",
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://mongo:27017/admin?tls=true&tlsallowinvalidcertificates=true&tlsallowinvalidhostnames=true",
    "database": "myDB",
    "collection": "myCollection",
    "change.stream.full.document": "updateLookup",
    "poll.max.batch.size": 5000,
    "topic.prefix": "topic",
    "copy.existing": true,
    "copy.existing.allow.disk.use": true,
    "copy.existing.max.threads": 10,
    "output.format.value": "schema",
    "pipeline": "[{$project: {\"aql\": 0, \"wizard_expressions\": 0}}]",
    "copy.existing.pipeline": "[{$project: {\"aql\": 0, \"wizard_expressions\": 0}}]"
  }
```

Any advice here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I had to filter the columns prefixed by `fullDocument`.

> "pipeline": "[{$project: {"**fullDocument**.aql": 0, "**fullDocument**.wizard_expressions": 0}}]",
>
> "copy.existing.pipeline": "[{$project: {"**fullDocument**.aql": 0, "**fullDocument**.wizard_expressions": 0}}]"